# WPF Binding ItemsSource to a static method?

Tags: wpf, binding, methods, itemssource

I have the following static method in an class called "Article" :

```
public static ObservableCollection<Article> GetObservableCollection() { ... }
```

And I'd like to bind this directly to the ItemsSource property of a ComboBox but in the XAML not in code, I can't find the right syntax.

It should look something like this I think (EmacGbscCore is the assembly containing Article object) :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static EmacGbscCore:Article.GetObservableCollection}}"
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to declare an `ObjectDataProvider` in the resources:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="data"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type EmacGbscCore:Article}"
                    MethodName="GetObservableCollection" />
```

And use this as the source of your binding:

```
ItemsSource"{Binding Source={StaticResource data}}"
```